# How to manipulate headers linking with CMake and CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, clion

Is there a way to create an alias for `#included` resources within one of the directives of CMakeLists.txt?

I am looking for a way to define something in the CMakeLists.txt so any occurrence of global resource like

```
#include <some/global/dependency/file.h>
```

will be aliased to the right resource, so CMake will also look for it in the following locations

```
#include "../file/is/here/file.h"
#include "file.h"
#include <alias.h>
```

---

Why?

I am working on a very complex project with containerized build system. Means, lot of manual work should be done to make the project play well in any IDE. Actually, there are lot of sub projects within the main project that being individually compiled with lot of dedicate configurations.

I am using CLion as my IDE. CLion support CMake out of the box, but my project is not using cmake :) I created custom CMakeLists.txt file by simply including lot of folders (with header files) by using  `include_directories()` directive, and for now it works very well. It able to recognize symbols/navigation/macros generation and build a nice index of the included files. 
But I have this problem where, in some files CLion not able to recognize the file path because the `#include` refers to global (prebuilt / containerized) path/file which does not exist on my real file system, but generally, any such resource exist in the project under different path. So I wonder is there a way to just instruct CMake to do the following:

1. IF asked to `#include` something from XXX path
2. THEN first look for it under YYY path or ZZZ path etc'...
3. if the resource not found in step 2 above, look for it under XXX path

I will appreciate if you can help me to improve the question and title by editing it with better terminology etc'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake by itself doesn't provide a compiler, it is even not a build tool. So, if a compiler cannot replace include directories "on fly", CMake cannot do so.

If you are allowed to copy headers - copy them in proper location, so `include_directories()` will work.

If you are allowed to copy and modify sources, you may copy them into the new location and run scanner on them, which modifies `#include` directives.

Otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean scaner? Thanks

Comment: By "scanner" I mean a script or a program, which finds `#include` directives (with regular exressions or such), and replace them.

Comment: thanks for helping out. I accepting the answer. I wish there would be more interesting solutions to this problem.